# How to use Angular 4 with existing Express project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I have an existing Express project located at ~/Documents/projects/express-project, and I want to use Angular 4 with it. I have tried using

```
ng new express-project --directory express-project
```

while in my projects directory, but it doesn't create the files needed for Angular and gives the following messages:

```
$ ng new express-project --directory express-project
error! express-project/.gitignore already exists.
error! express-project/package.json already exists.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Project 'express-project' successfully created.
```

I have also tried the following command:

```
ng build
```

but it complains about an angular-cli.json file. What do I need to do to get Angular 4 working with my existing project?

Comment: Here is my angular 4 with express project, may be you will find it useful: https://github.com/commercialsuicide/angular2-with-express-starter. It's called "angular 2", but there is an angular 4 inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found it best to create a folder with two subfolders for example

```
-express-project
    -server <-- copy the existing files from your project here
    -client <-- ng new here and set the build directory in the .angular-cli json to your desired path in the server dir.
```